# Delete a file without delete permission

Tags: java, file, io, delete-file

Is there any way in java one can delete a file with no delete permissions on file?

Comment: Can you enter sombody's apartment if you do not have a key?

Comment: @AlexR: That is conflating permission and capability ;-)

Comment: any shell script / batch script execution in java program that could make it possible?

Comment: No. the permissions also apply to any script you could run. That is the point of permissions. You need to get the owner of the file, or a superuser to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you mentioned shell script here is a partial work around: if you are on unix and your user can run `sudo` execute external command like `sudo rm -f YOUR_PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot delete a file if you don't have the permissions. In case you have write permissions, you can make it blank.

Comment: +1 for the workaround. Maybe  (probably not) you can also rename it.